# Prove that the expected value of the quadratic distance is n, where n is the number of steps.

Tags: probability, random-variables

A drunkard is standing in the middle of a very large town square. He begins to walk. Each step is a unit distance in one of the four directions East, West, North, and South. All four possible directions are equally probable. The direction for each step is chosen independently of the direction of the others. The drunkard takes a total of n steps. Verify that the quadratic distance of the drunkard to his starting point after n steps has expected value n, irrespective of the value of n.

What I tried:

Let $d$ be the squared distance that the drunkard travelled.

Let $X_i$ be the change in the x-distance in the ith step and $Y_i$ be the y-distance in the ith step. Therefore d = $\sum_{i=0}^n X_i^2$ + $\sum_{i=0}^n Y_i^2$. The expected value of d will then be

E($d^2$) = $\sum_{d=0}^{d_{max}} d \cdot P(d)$ = $\sum_{d=0}^{d_{max}} $($\sum_{i=0}^n X_i^2 + \sum_{i=0}^n Y_i^2$) $\cdot$ P($\sum_{i=0}^n X_i^2 and \sum_{i=0}^n Y_i^2$)

I don't know how to proceed from here. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if you start at $(a,b)$ and randomly take one step in any of the four directions, the expected squared distance from the origin is now $E=a^2+b^2+1$.  To see this we compute:  $$E=\frac 14\left[(a^2+(b+1)^2+a^2+(b-1)^2+(a+1)^2+b^2+(a-1)^2+b^2\right]=\frac 14\left[4a^2+4b^2+4\right]$$

Your claim now follows by induction.  That is, we use the above observation to conclude that $E[n]=E[n-1]+1$ and we are done.