# Variance of a simple plane random walk

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have a few doubts on how to solve the following problem, from *Understanding Probability* by Henk Tijms.

> A drunkard is standing in the middle of a very large town square. He
>   begins to walk. Each step is a unit distance in one of the four
>   directions East, West, North and South. All four possible directions
>   are equally probable. The direction for each step is chosen
>   independently of the direction of the others. The drunkard takes a
>   total of $n$ steps.
>
> 1. verify that the quadratic distance of the drunkard to his starting point after $n$ steps has expected value $n$, irrespective of the
>      value of $n$.
> 2. use the definition of variance to explain why the expected value of the distance of the drunkard to his starting point after $n$ steps
>      cannot be equal to $\sqrt{n}$. (hint: use the fact that $P(X=c)=1$ for
>      some constant $c$ if $\mathrm{var}(X)=0$.

Regarding the first question, I found an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684861/prove-that-the-expected-value-of-the-quadratic-distance-is-n-where-n-is-the-num).

Regarding the second question, I don't know how to apply the hint. Maybe at first I should show that the variance of the quadratic distance is equal to zero? But then how does the mentioned fact help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d_n$ denote the distance after $n$-steps. In the post you link to, it is shown that the square of the distance, satisfies

$$\mathbf{E}[d_n^2] = n.$$

Now consider the formula for the variance of $d_n$

\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(d_n) & = \mathbf{E}[d_n^2] - \mathbf{E}[d_n]^2 \\
& = n - \mathbf{E}[d_n]^2.
\end{align*}

If it were the case that $\mathbf{E}[d_n]^2 = n$ then the above would give:

$$\text{Var}(d_n) = 0,$$

which in turn would imply that there is some constant $c$ such that $P(d_n = c) = 1$. However this is clearly not the case for $n > 1$.

In particular (assuming the walk starts from $(0,0)$) after two steps the walk can be at site $(2,0)$ or $(1,1)$, and others... But focusing on these two cases, in the first we would have $d_2 = 2$ whilst in the later $d_2 = \sqrt{2}$, so $P[d_2 = 2] > 0$ and $P[d_2 = \sqrt{2} ] > 0$, contradicting the claim.

Comment: Do you mean: "If it were the case that $\mathbf{E}[d_n]^2=n$, then ..."? I see how the argument works now, thank you.

Comment: Yes, corrected! Thanks.